# Термин для набора разных реализаций одной программы

Tags: терминология

В качестве курсовой работы разработал игру на несколько платформ: одинаковый интерфейс, функционал, кодовая база разная. Играть можно как офлайн (против бота), так и по сети (через сервер). Теперь пишу документацию, никак не могу подобрать определения. Это не программный комплекс (который является цельной системой), не программный пакет (в котором программы с близким, но различным функционалом, в рамках одного ПК). Ничего лучше `набора программ` в голову не приходит, но такого определения нет. Подскажете что-нибудь?

Comment: Часто используется название _семейство программ_.

Comment: Кроссплатформное ПО